# how to automaticall update table date from MySQL localhost to MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I have a test DB in localhost. In this DB I have a table call user. I have the same user table in MySQL server. My question is if I update the localhost user table then it will automatically update the user tabel of the server. IS it possible? 
Thank you

Comment: No, it will not automatically update the server table. Yes, it is possible to do this, but there are lots of different solutions depending on your exact circumstances and requirements.

Comment: you can write code in method and execute all of them on server, I have previously imported whole .sql file in asp.net mvc by some library, I am not sure about your environment. did you try to execute them through the code

Answer (score -1):

If you have done it by editing the database manually like with **PhpMyAdmin** or something like that it wouldn't be updated in the other database.
But if you would update from your application then it would become possible by replicating the query two times one for the local db and the other for the MySQL Server.